# Why $w(0,t)=w(L,t)=0\Longrightarrow w_t(0,t)=w_t(L,t)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let $w$ be a $C^2$ function in two variables, $x$ and $t$. The domain of $x$ is $[0,L]$ whilst the domain of $t$ is $t\geq 0$. Suppose that $w(0,t)=w(L,t)=0$. The apparently  $w_t(0,t)=w_t(L,t)=0$. I don't really know why this happpens. Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $w(0,t)=0$ for all $t\geqslant 0$,
\begin{align*}
w_t(0,t)&=\lim_{h\to 0 } \frac{w(0,t+h)-w(0,t)}h\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0 } \frac{0-0}h\\
&=0.
\end{align*} In words, $w$ is constant (it is 0) on $x=0$, so it is not changing in time there. The same is true for $x=L$.